# Automorphism of Tree

Tags: group-theory, trees, geometric-group-theory

Let $\sigma$ and $\theta$ be two automorphisms of tree $X$. I want to show that min$_{v\in V(X)}d(v,\sigma(v))=$min$_{v\in V(X)}d(\theta^{-1}\sigma\theta(v),v)$.

I know every automorphism of tree is either translation or inversion or rotation. So if $\sigma$ is rotation, then we done. But i do not have any idea for cases translation or inversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from $d(\theta^{-1}\sigma\theta(v),v) = d(\sigma(\theta(v)),\theta(v))$.

Comment: Yes. To elaborate, since $\theta$ is an automorphism, it preserves distances, so that $d(x,y)=d(\theta(x), \theta(y))$. In particular, $d(\theta^{-1} \sigma \theta(v),v) = d(\sigma(\theta(v)),\theta(v))$. The minimum of this quantity over $v \in V(X)$ is the same as the minimum of $d(\sigma(u),u)$ over $u \in V(X)$ because $\theta$ is bijective on $V$.